# didReceiveRemoteNotification NOT called on IOS 8.2 / Xcode 6.2

Tags: ios, xcode, push-notification, pushwoosh

My app not receveing push notification.
I use on IOS 8.2 and registration is:

```
if([[UIApplication sharedApplication] respondsToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)]) {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge) categories:nil]];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
}
```

I see the server send notification but my device not received...
How can I resolve?

Comment: do you get any feedback from pushwoosh? are you sure the certificates are right? are you sure the token push ir right? is didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken being called?

Comment: @jcesarmobile yes, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken is being called! and the certificate is right...

Comment: Are you sending from the sandbox server? I assume you are in dev.

Comment: No I'm in Distribuction...

Comment: @Mikael ... yes... I'm sending from sandbox... while my app is distribuction...